# Meaning and case of обиженных

Tags: значения, падежи

I can't find any information about this word on wiktionary.

Example sentence: *Он стал на защиту обиженных.*

Comment: [wiktionary:Обиженный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case is genitive (родительный падеж): стал на защиту ***кого***?

*обиженные* means oppressed, disadvantaged (people), it is in plural form. Singular masculine would be *обиженный*.